# Azure v12 Database Login Users

Tags: azure-sql-database

In v12 Sql Azure, I want to see all the Logins. I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals
```

but get an error of:

```
Invalid object name 'sys.server_principals'.
```

Is there an alternate to this?

Answer (score 2):

Try `select * from sys.sql_logins`

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this. It seemed to work if you go from master. I then tried to automate it using: select * from master.sys.sql_login but get error: Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.sql_login' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information - Cross database queries using three or four part names [are not supported]. This is what that error text means. Hope that helps.